# Ubuntu 12.10 is compatible with an Intel HD 4000 integrated video card?

Tags: nvidia

I want to know if Ubuntu 12.10 is compatible with an Intel HD 4000 integrated video card .

Comment: I can see you added a `nvdia` tag to your question. Is your system optimus enabled system? The answer may be different based on this.

Comment: can you provide more details of your computer.

Comment: I would guess yes. Intel video cards in general are well supported on Ubuntu, but their performance tends to be not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using 12.10 in i945G (GMA 950), older than GMA 4000 and still running smoothly. So why don't you try it with live cd first?